# How to install writable shared and user specific data files with setuptools?

Tags: python, linux, windows, setuptools

I know package_data. But it is for readonly data inside the package. Or is this assumption wrong? How to install shared or user specific *writeable* data? For example to ProgramData or AppData on Windows. I'm interested in a solution for linux, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption seems right to me (*package data* should be *read-only*). For writable data: either let the user choose a target directory, or pick one directory according to a common convention. But this can not happen at *install time*. It's probably better to have your library or application check if these *shared* directories and files exist when they are needed, and if they don't then create them on the fly.

For example a pretty common convention is the [*XDG Base Directory Specification*](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). These libraries can help write code according to this specification:

- [*`platformdirs`*](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) (preferred, up-to-date and well maintained)
- [*`appdirs`*](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) (outdated)
- [*`xdgappdirs`*](https://pypi.org/project/xdgappdirs/) (outdated)

Comment: A call to site_data_dir("app", "company") returns '/usr/share/gnome-xorg/app'. Not what I expected. I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: Even if this would return sensible paths, I still don't know how to integrate this in my setup.py file.

Comment: Then use another of the many available functions. What is it that you are expecting as a result?

Comment: @MartinFehrs This definitely shouldn't be part of your setup script. In the code of your library or application, check if these _shared_ directories and/or files exist, if they don't then create them.

Comment: I expected /usr/share/app or /usr/local/share/app. When I call site_data_dir(appname, appauthor, multipath=True) I get a list of paths including both. But even those two paths aren't what i want. I think /var/lib/app would be right directory, because it is writable.

Comment: These projects follow the [_XDG Base Directory Specification_](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), it's a pretty common one. Pick another convention if it feels like it would be a better choice for your users. I was just giving you an example, but seems like you got the point of my answer.