# Add custom action to setup.py

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have the project with such structure:

```
Project/
    Project/
        __init__.py
        config.py
    setup.py
    .gitignore
```

`config.py` contains two variables (`LOGIN`, `PASS`) and is added to `.gitignore`.

I would like to add custom action to `setup.py` then run `python setup.py install` than triggered creating `config.py` with some `inputs("Please write your login/pass")` prior to installation of package.

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to do any customization at *install time*. It is good practice to do customization at *run time*, usually at the start of the first run.

At the start of your program, you should check if *login* and *pass* are somehow available. If *login* and *pass* are not available, then ask the user to enter them and save the values in a file. Usually such files should be saved in *user configuration directory*. Typically you would use the [*platformdirs*](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) library to get the right location for such a file.

Something like that:

```py
import pathlib

import platformdirs

user_config_dir = platformdirs.user_config_dir('MyApp', 'tibhar940')
user_config_path = pathlib.Path(user_config_dir, 'config.cfg')

if user_config_path.is_file():
    # read
else:
    # prompt the user and save in file
```

***Related***:

- [How to setup application to personalize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60399987/11138259)
- [How to install writable shared and user specific data files with setuptools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60158692/11138259)