# How to ask setuptools to add a file somewhere in user's home directory

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I am writing a python script that can be run as a Nautilus script (but not only).

I use `setuptools`. Imagine that in my `setup.py` I use `entry_points` that creates a command named `my_nautilus_script` (this is working well).

I would like that `pip install my_nautilus_script` also adds say a `xxx.sh` in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` which calls in turn `my_nautilus_script` command.

A few questions about that:

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it a good way to look at the problem? is there a better/cleaner alternative? of course, the user can be asked to create `xxx.sh` him/her-self... but this is not what I want.
3. As a Nautilus script, my script is *particularly* intended for Linux users but **not only**. I do not want `pip install` to fail for Windows users).

Comment: Not possible. Not a good way to look at the problem. This is beyond Python packaging scope. I recommend you look into packaging tooling specific to the operating system (apt/deb, yum/rpm, pacman, msi, snap, etc.).

Comment: That's what I thought. On the other hand, I think apt/deb etc. are certainly overkill for my small project (even though this could be an opportunity for me to learn...)

Comment: Typically these things can also be done during the first run-time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64459990

Comment: OK but in that case (nautilus script) there will be no first run-time as long as the script is not placed in the right folder (vicious circle)